# Trying to load an Image on screen

Tags: phaser-framework, httpserver

Trying to load an Image on screen. I just want to set this image in the background, but can't get past the black screen. Thanks

Using http-server

**in the public folder**

```
public    
-assets    
--img    
---xlogo.png  
--js
---index.js
-systems    
--phaser.js
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>X Game</title>

    <script src="systems/phaser/phaser.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="test-1"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**-INDEX.JS-**

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'test-1', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {

    game.load.image('xlogo', 'assets/img/xlogo.png');

}

function create() {

    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'xlogo');

}

function update() {
}
```

Comment: is it a path issue or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Can see your other js files. Chrome has any error?
Let's try this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage

Comment: i just have phaser.js and index.js in the respected folders shown in post. Chrome has no errors

Comment: its working now but I still don't know the issue. maybe it was a Chrome refresh issue?

Comment: long pressing left mouse in to reload button beside of address in chrome, choose [empty cache and reload] or [hard reload] page, maybe It cached your old page.